# DELETE all where MySQL foreign key constraint does not fail

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a few records but am getting the following error:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

The thing is, the foreign key constraint is failing for only 1 or 2 of my 100 records I wish to delete. I wish to write a query which deletes these 98-99 records, ***skipping the 1 or 2 which failed***, which I can later manually inspect and delete/modify. Not stopping because of some single problematic record, but continuing with the others, ignoring that.

Is there a neat way to do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to `LEFT JOIN` the referencing table and add a condition saying that the row is missing in that table.

For example:

```
DELETE a FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
WHERE b.a_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ignore:

```
DELETE IGNORE ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: `DELETE IGNORE` doesn't achieve the goal. According to http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/02/02/stop-delete-ignore-on-tables-with-foreign-keys-can-break-replication/, in 5.0, _no_ rows are deleted in case of a FOREIGN KEY error, but in 5.1 and 5.5, rows _up until_ the error occurs are deleted, and _subsequent rows are left untouched_.

Comment: Neither did I, actually, until I noticed recently that my log purge cron job wasn't really doing its job :)