# Delete Ignore behaving differently on different versions

Tags: mysql

Consider the following 2 tables:

```
Users
------
id | name
1  | David
2  | John
3  | Sam

User_Payments
-----
id | user_id | amount
1  | 1       | 100
2  | 2       | 200
```

`User_Payments.user_id REFERENCES Users(id) ON DELETE NO ACTION`

^ This means that users that are referenced in user_payments may not be deleted.

If we run the query:

```
DELETE IGNORE FROM Users;
```

Depending on the version, MySQL will either:

1. Delete Sam, because he is the only user that can be safely deleted
2. Hit an error, and won't delete anything

[Since this is version dependent](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44987), I want to find a query that will fulfill #1.

**I would like to delete all users that are not referenced by any other table.**

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978304/delete-all-where-mysql-foreign-key-constraint-does-not-fail), but I don't want to check every other table to see if the user_id is being referenced or not.

If I have many, many, tables, this approach won't work.

```
users
user_payments
user_info
user_keywords
user_logs
user_etc
...
```

All the user_* tables will be able to reference some users(id).

So how can I write a query that deletes only users that are not referenced by any other table?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 3**: This might help:

`DELETE FROM Users WHERE`

```
SELECT CONCAT('Users.id NOT EXISTS (SELECT ', t.table_name, '.user_id FROM t WHERE ', t.table_name, '.user_id=Users.id) AND')
FROM information_schema.tables t
WHERE t.table_name LIKE 'user\_%'
AND t.table_schema = 'ENTER_DB_NAME_HERE'
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/sqlstatement.sql';
```

And then (rolls eyes, so sorry), after concatenating, remove the training `AND` and append a semicolon.

**EDIT 2**: The below is a revised, and possibly stupidly expensive, proposal:

`DELETE IGNORE FROM Users`

```
SELECT CONCAT('LEFT JOIN ', t.table_name, ' ON ', t.table_name, '.user_id=Users.id')
FROM information_schema.tables t
WHERE t.table_name LIKE 'user\_%'
AND t.table_schema = 'ENTER_DB_NAME_HERE'
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/sqlstatement.sql';
```

`WHERE`

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.table_name, '.user_id IS NULL AND')
FROM information_schema.tables t
WHERE t.table_name LIKE 'user\_%'
AND t.table_schema = 'ENTER_DB_NAME_HERE'
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/sqlstatement2.sql';
```

And you'll have to manually concatenate these together. There must be a better way, sorry for the spam.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I see this won't work as you need to check *all* the tables for each `user_id`.

Well, you could use create a stored procedure, using dynamic SQL and a bunch of `CONCAT`'s and loops, however, looking at [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/mysql-how-to-drop-all-tables-starting-with-a-prefix), I think something like the following might get you on the right (and safest) track:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DELETE IGNORE FROM Users LEFT JOIN ', t.table_name, ' ON ', t.table_name, '.user_id=Users.id WHERE ', t.table_name, '.user_id IS NULL;')
FROM information_schema.tables t
WHERE t.table_name LIKE 'user\_%'
AND t.table_schema = 'ENTER_DB_NAME_HERE'
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/sqlstatements.sql';
```

And then:

```
SOURCE /tmp/sqlstatements.sql;
```

to execute (but **check** the file contents first). I haven't tested the above, apologies, but hopefully it will at least help. Much easier than a stored procedure. Another way would be to do the looping in another language (e.g. Python), but I think the above should do the trick.

Comment: I can try this, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution. On a different version of MySQL, `DELETE IGNORE` would delete everything that could be safely deleted. I imagine MySQL does do something similar to what your answer is suggesting in the background - i.e it scans all the tables to see if there is a foreign key to users.id or not. If there's not another answer I'll accept yours. That was the initial solution I had in mind too.

Comment: Right (https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/02/02/stop-delete-ignore-on-tables-with-foreign-keys-can-break-replication/ is another link that highlights the issue). I'm sorry that my solution is still rather manual in some ways. I'm assuming you've read https://stackoverflow.com/q/7232704/2178980 etc. Doesn't seem to be a more elegant solution than to (in some way) list all the tables. Personally I would do it in Python, although I appreciate you're probably looking for a pure SQL solution. Not much more I can suggest short of a stored proc!

Comment: I only just reaslized the question, basically: for ```ON DELETE RESTRICT```, if error, accept the error, and carry on (rather than failing). Interesting question, yet I still cannot find anything in the docs. Probably boils down to a canonical relational DB design decision...